# Weird special character issue in all browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, special-characters

Today Chrome started behaving in a rather weird way. Some websites no longer display special characters properly. For example:

- I see a `6` instead of an `á` but if I copy and paste the character itself I see an `á`
- I see a `й` instead of an `é` but if I copy and paste the character itself I see an `é`

The list goes on. Here comes the weird part: If I fire up Internet Explorer I see the same but in Firefox I do not see the text at all.

I tried setting the character encoding but nothing works.

It is even more weird that **not all** websites work the same way. On some sites everything is fine from all browsers (like gmail) but others have this issue. As far as I can remember I did not install any new software since yesterday. I'm using Windows 7.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Did anyone happen to change your regional settings - language in particular?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: In my regional settings (and internet settings) I have Hungary (which is OK) and I use 2 keyboard layouts: `EN` and `HU`. This was the case before but I noticed a small change: If I swap to `EN` the back tick (**`**) works if I press it once. Before this character issue appeared the back tick was working in a weird way: If I pressed it once nothing happened **but** if I pressed any key after the back tick press *both* characters appeared on the srceen.

Comment: I noticed this behaviour on Windows 7 running Visual Basic - I thought it was a feature :)

Comment: This back tick behaviour shouldn't be connected with your issue and is expected, see [Dead key on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key).

Comment: Might be a corrupt font. You can identify and adjust the fonts used on problematic pages by playing around in Chrome's inspector. Given that it's not happening in Firefox, the issue could be a default font potentially shared by Chrome and IE. Instructions for changing them: [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416) and [IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-webpage-colors-fonts)

Comment: Yea I just realized that yesterday. It was a corrupted `Verdana` font. Don't know how it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

It was a corrupted `Verdana` font. I don't know how it became corrupted but deleting/reinstalling it solved the problem.